# Trying to push Rails 4.2.1 app to Heroku sqlite error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

So I read the thread on that similar question, but still confused.  This is my gem file.

I changed all the sqlite3 gems in my gemfile to gem 'pg',   '0.7.0'  I changed the all the sqlite3 in the database.yml file to postgresql.  I did a bundle install, and then heroku create, and then git push heroku master and this had multiple problems trying to install sqlite3.

Comment: Can you include your gem file?  Generally, you don't want to be replacing gems for different environments, just bundle them under the right groups.  So, for instance, you could have a development group with sqlite and a production group with pg all in the same gemfile.

Comment: source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg',          '0.17.1'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

Comment: Sorry please update your OP with your gemfile with proper formatting.  And yes, it is very common to use sqlite in dev/test and pg in production, but you shouldn't need to remove sqlite from your gemfile to do this - it should within a group like `group :development, :test do` so it is used for development and test.

Comment: I read the Heroku does not use sqlite3 so I changed to postgresql.

Comment: I did that.  I changed the sqlite3 gem to pg gem.  Not sure how to change the format of the op.

Comment: I see you have a development/test group.  Remove `pg` from this group and add back `sqlite`.  That way `sqlite` will be used for development and test and Postgres will be used for production (since you have `pg` in your production group).  Re: OP - click on edit and then just add the gemfile there.  It is hard to read stuff like that in a comment where it is not formatted like code.

Comment: ok here is the gemfilesource 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg',          '0.17.1'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

Comment: sorry not having any luck adding a file to a comment.

Comment: Similarly, your `database.yml` file should have `sqlite` defined for your development and test environments and `postgreSQL` for production.  It would ideal if you could edit your original post and paste both your `gemfile` and your `database.yml` file into it, then save changes.  Copy/paste the file contents into the post body.

Comment: I did copy/paste the file contents into the post body.  I'll try it again.source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

Comment: Sorry I dont know why the format is lost when I post into body.

Comment: This is not the OP body - it is a comment.  I mean edit your original question.  Regardless, I think I understand your problem and will post an answer.

Comment: OK @John I posted an answer which should help but I'll check back later if you are still running into issues.  GL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very common to run with SQLite in development and test and a different database like PostgreSQL in production.  Rails makes it easy to do this.

In your Gemfile, you can use groups to specify which gems should be installed in each environment.  So, in this scenario, your gemfile would contain something like:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
end
```

The first time you add production gems, you should run:

```
bundle install --without production
```

to update your `gemfile.lock`.

Similarly, in `database.yml`, you should define sqlite for development and test and postgresql for production.  Here is an example:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  database: signup
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: xxxx
  password: yyyy
```

Finally, make sure that you commit gemfile changes to production before you attempt to deploy to Heroku.

Comment: Thanks Steve, the problem was I did not do a commit before deploying to Heroku.  I left the gemfile and database.yml alone.  Thanks again.